# Sending data from C process to Python process using pipes

Tags: python, c, pipe

I'm trying to send data from a C program to a python program (both are running simultaneously). I'm attempting to use the popen function in C. The way I understand it, whatever I write to the file descriptor in C can be read from stdin in the python program. However, the python program appears to hang at the point where it reads from stdin. Any suggestions?

Here's the C program:

**test.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    FILE * fp = popen("sudo python display.py", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("popen error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int inc = 0;
    char buf[10];

    while(1) {
        sprintf(buf, "%d", inc);
        fputs(buf, fp);
        inc++;
        sleep(1);
    }


    return (0);
}
```

Here is the python program, which should read the value of "inc" and output it

**display.py**

```
import sys

value = 0

while(True):
    value = sys.stdin.read()
    print value
```

The program seems to hang at *value = sys.stdin.read()*. I have tried readline() and readlines() as well with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You rather should use [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html) instead of mixing `sprintf` (which is unsafe, prefer [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html)) with `fputs`.

You really want to output whole lines (because [textual protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_protocol) are so convenient to debug). And use `readline` on the Python side.

At last, a `FILE*` obtained by [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) is not even guaranteed to be line-buffered (but could have a much larger buffer, perhaps 4Kbytes or more). You might set its buffer using [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html) but you really should **flush explicitly the `FILE*` buffer with [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)**. If you don't, the output could stay in the buffer for a long time (without any actual  [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) done by `stdio` functions like `fprintf` or `fputs`) so the [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) stays empty.

<sup>(so you have problems even on the C side)</sup>

> The program seems to hang at value = sys.stdin.read().

I guess that not a single byte was actually written by your C code (you could check by using [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)) because your `fputs` stayed in the buffer. You might need to wait a long time (perhaps 1000 seconds, to fill a buffer of a few kilobytes) to have it actually write something on the pipe, because you forgot the `fflush` .

A `popen`-ed file should absolutely be `pclose`d.

So you should replace your (incorrect) `while` loop with:

```
while(1) {
    fprintf(fp, "%d\n", inc);
    inc++;
    fflush(fp);
    sleep(1);
}
```

And your loop should be exited somehow. Perhaps you might catch some [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) -probably `SIGTERM`- (but be sure to read [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)). Be sure to `pclose` (to avoid zombie processes).

<sup>(I am assuming you are on Linux or some other POSIX system)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it for me

Answer (score 4):

`readline()` would work if you were outputting *lines* from your C program.

Since you never print a newline, `readline` will wait forever.

`read()` with no parameters will wait until the C program exits (or otherwise closes stdout). Again this is never going to happen with your program

Comment: But without any `fflush` on the C side, and only a few bytes written every second, OP needs to wait a long time for something to happen. I guess that the Python process never gets a single byte in practice (since OP needs probably to wait several hundred seconds for that to happen on his original code)